# TypeError [ERR_INVALID_REPL_INPUT] [ERR_INVALID_REPL_INPUT]: Listeners for `uncaughtException` cannot be used in the REPL

Tags: blockchain, truffle, ganache

I am trying to test my first blockchain application.This is my code

```
var Contest = artifacts.require("./Contest.sol");
contract("Contest",function(accounts){
//to check if getting initialized correctly
it("initializes with two contestants", function(){
    return Contest.deployed().then(function(instance){
        return instance.contestantsCount();
    }).then(function(count){
        assert.equal(count,2);
    });
});
});
```

But i am getting this error:

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_REPL_INPUT] [ERR_INVALID_REPL_INPUT]: Listeners 
for `uncaughtException` cannot be used in the REPL
```

Environment

```
Operating System: Microsoft Windows
Truffle v5.0.2 (core: 5.0.2)
Solidity v0.5.0 (solc-js)
Node v14.17.1
```

Answer (score 0):

There should be no comma.
It should be:

```py
X = faces[::-1]
y = faces[:-1:]
```